# unexpected long indent after colon in web-mode

Tags: indentation, web-mode, comment

I have some trouble locating the source of 8 tabs and 3 spaces more than the previous indentation when I'm inside js inside web-mode. These appear after a line that ends with a colon. Example (note that in emacs these are tabs of width 4, except the last 3 spaces which are actually spaces):

```
        // bind event to schedule visibility toggle:
                                           $('input#scheduleswitch').parent().change(function() {
```

Anyone a suggestion what might be causing this long indent? 
Could it be a case-statement related indentation?

Comment: Make sure you have the newest version of `web-mode`, if you have it, and the problem still persists, then it's very likely a bug that should be reported.

Comment: The problem persist with a clean .emacs and .emacs.d with a fresh install of web-mode. I reported it here: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/1037 . Including a minimal non-working example.

Comment: Any suggestions how I might debug this myself? The git issues don't seem to be actively checked/replied to :s